# Double integration proof for expectation of a random variable.

Tags: probability, integration, random-variables, expectation

Let X $\ge 0$ be a continious random variable. Prove $E(X) = \int_0^\infty P (X>t)dt$.

Here is the proof: Denote by f the density of X, then

$\int_0^\infty P(X > t)dt = \int_0^\infty\int_t^\infty f(x)dxdt = \int_0^\infty f(x) \int_0^xdt dx = \int_0^\infty f(x)*x dx = E(X).$

I don't understand how $\int_0^\infty\int_t^\infty f(x)dxdt = \int_0^\infty f(x) \int_0^xdt dx$.

Comment: This is a consequence of Fubini's Theorem that let's you switch the order of integration (see here: http://users.math.msu.edu/users/gnagy/teaching/11-fall/mth234/L22-234.pdf)

Comment: wait so how come the limits changed from 0 to infinity and t to infinity -> 0 to infinity and 0 to x?

Comment: happy new year by the way :)

Comment: Ohh, nice proof thank you!

Comment: The limits of integration changed because the order of integration changed. You couldn't possibly have $\int_t^\infty \int_0^\infty f(x) dtdx$ because then there's a variable in a limit of the outer integral. The region of integration is $\{(t,x)~:~ 0\leq t <\infty, t\leq x<\infty\}$. This can be rewritten as $\{(t,x)~:~ 0 \leq x <\infty, 0\leq t \leq x\}$, which gives you the new bounds. Drawing a sketch of the region in the $(t,x)$-plane can help you see this.

Comment: Simply write $\int_0^\infty P(X>t)\,dt=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty [x>t]\,dFdt$ and exchange order of integration - correct limits pop out automatically.